# Parsing remote or local XML using angularjs and ionicframework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xml-parsing, ionic-framework

New to angularjs and started working on creating application where data will be received by xml which is located on server.

I searched a lot about xml parsing in angularjs using IONIC framework. But didn't get solution.

Can anyone provide me with tutorial or example it would be great.

Comment: i solved my problem using this link
this is really helpful
check this out http://www.amitavroy.com/justread/content/articles/working-xml-angular-js

Answer (score 1):

If you can switch to REST/JSON on the server it is pretty much the norm nowadays for communicating to/from js apps and much, much easier to handle on the client.